# Can't restore SQL Server 2008 from backup

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, backup, restore

I'm currently trying to restore my database.

The step I follow is the executing the query

```
Restore Database vaio 
from disk = 'C:\Users\DB101209123928_Diff_20120312.bak'
with replace;
```

But I'm getting the following error.

> Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'vaio' database.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that there is no database named `vaio`in your restore file.

There is not much to help here. Make sure you have the correct restore file

Answer (score 3):

You can try this query first to see what's contained in your `.bak` file:

```
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(255)
SET @FileName = N'C:\Users\DB101209123928_Diff_20120312.bak' 

RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = @FileName
```

Once you know what's in the backup file, you can then restore the appropriate database from it.

Answer (score 0):

First check header by below query,

`restore headeronly from disk ='D:\anuj\userpro.bak'`

It will give you information like: database name, backup name, position, username...

Now execute the following commands to restore database:

```
restore database school from disk='D:\anuj\school.bak' with file =1
```

Here, replace `file =1` is the position given by above query.

Comment: Your answer is poorly formatted. Please check your spelling and use the tools to make clear what is code and what is text. You should also explain what each command is doing.